# Virtual desktop scroll with mouse not working since upgrade to Kubuntu 21.04

Tags: kubuntu

Previously I was running Kubuntu 20.04 (and many versions before that) and I've had center roller mouse scrolling across 6 virtual desktops working for literally years. Yesterday I upgraded to 21.04 and it no longer works. I've been diving through System Settings looking for the control but cannot find it.

Workspace Behaviour -> Virtual Desktops (no)

Input Devices -> Mouse (no)

Can someone point me to where this setting exists?

Thanks

Comment: Why install 21.04 with only a few months left of support?

Comment: Two distinct situations: (1) is going out of your way to do a release-upgrade from a LTS to a non-LTS and going out of your way I mean specifically changing the default settings that would suggest a release upgrade *only* after the next LTS had been released, i.e., 22.04 (April 2022); (1.1) you'll soon need to upgrade to 21.10 and (2) yes, maybe related.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - I have exactly this problem in a LTS 22.04.

Comment: [Cannot change desktop with mouse scroll when Folder View is selected in Kubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1423940/925128).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To anyone who runs across this in the future. The problem (most likely a bug) is that it's not working when the desktop is configured in 'Folder View'. Switching to 'Desktop View' resolves the problem.

Right click on your desktop. Choose (as appropriate for your version of KDE) either 'Configure Desktop' or 'Configure Desktop and Wallpaper'.In the LAyout choice choose 'Desktop'.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer further specifies the problem but without solving it.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround, given I have found this in 22.04 LTS too, is to use the pager widget (on the panel or on the desktop) and the mouse scroll on that instead of the desktop surface.

Answer (score 0):

In Kubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, do the following:

1. Right-click the Desktop to open the "Desktop Folder Settings" dialog
2. Click on the "Mouse Actions" in the left panel
3. In the right panel, click on the drop-down field next to the item "Vertical-Scroll"
4. Choose the menu item "Switch Desktop"
5. Click OK.
6. Done! The scroll wheeel should now allow switching desktops.

If you have multiple monitors, you may have to do this for each monitor's desktop.

You don't need to mess with setting either "Layout: Folder View" nor "Layout: Desktop" as another answer suggests.